# Multiple select dropdown in laravel

Tags: drop-down-menu, laravel, edit

Here is my code in the view, I want to display a dropdown that contains the selected data in an edit view.

```
{{Form::select('Select_targets[]', $_targets,Input::old('Select_target', $profile->Target_idTarget-1), array('multiple' => true))}}
```

I tried this code but it just displays one selected value. Please I need your help!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have an error around your old input and default values for the dropdown. Here is a stripped down example that does work:

Controller:

```
//current selected
$target = 3;

/array with options
$targets[1] = 'target 1';
$targets[2] = 'target 2';
$targets[3] = 'target 3';

return View::make('form')->with('targets',$targets)->with('target',$target);
```

View:

```
{{ Form::open() }}
{{ Form::select('targets[]', $targets, Request::old('targets') ? Request::old('targets') : $target, array('multiple' => true)); }}
{{ Form::submit('send') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

use wherein method of laravel incase you want to take all the option as query from request

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).